# How to call library API of react-native-curved-bottom-bar

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, react-navigation

please help me with the api library call.

I'm using the **"react-native-curved-bottom-bar"** library, where the readme lists the **setVisible(boolean)** function to hide the menu. However, I don't know where and how to call this function.

Link to the package:
https://github.com/hoaphantn7604/react-native-curved-bottom-bar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a component has a function available, you have to call that function on the component reference directly. The common way to do this is to store the instance in a ref, and then call the function on the ref. Ex:

```js
  const tabBarRef = useRef(null);

  const hideTabBar = () => {
    tabBarRef.current?.setVisible(false);
  };

  return <TabBar ref={tabBarRef} />;
```

You should access the instance optionally (`.current?.setVisible`) because the ref won't be populated until the first render of the screen.